# Format exception when I am converting to Int32

Tags: c#

While i am trying to convert a value to Int32, I get an error format exception, meaning the value is not in the proper format. I think I am converting a value in right format though.

Comment: What value are you trying to convert? could you give as som more information or snippet?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the value(s) you're trying to convert..

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Int32.TryParse()` you can find documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You will get `FormatException` in cases such next:

```
Convert.ToInt32("foo");
Convert.ToInt32(5.5);
```

because

> FormatException
>
> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx)

Comment: It's interesting because Convert.ToInt32("1.00") will also fail with a format exception even though it can be converted to a valid int, but conversely, something like Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal("1.00")) is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "123";
int i = 0;
if (int.TryParse(str, out i))
{
    //do your logic here
}
```

Share your code here, you might missed something

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the hint is in "I think I am converting a value in right format though"

Are you sure your number is formatted according to your current culture?

If not, it's Int32.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32%)
[details here][1] that you should be using

[1]: http://Int32.TryParse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32%)

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the type of the value you are passing in to such functions by using the `GetType()`.

The condition where I was stuck in this issue was conversion of a dynamically generated **stringyfied decimal value to int**. Figured out the type of the value using the `GetType()` and first converting it into double then int solved the problem.